# Static file Path call in node js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, server, static-files

I have Created a server-side app that can retrieve the index.html file in that directory.

**The code is as following,**

```
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')

const port = process.env.PORT || 1337;

const server = http.createServer(function (req, res){
    if(req.url.match(/^\/static/))
        return respondStatic(req,res)

    return respondNotFound(req,res)
});

server.listen(port)

function respondStatic(req,res){
    const filename = `${__dirname}/public${req.url.split('/static')[1]}`
    fs.createReadStream(filename)
        .on('error',()=> respondNotFound(req,res))
        .pipe(res)

    console.log(req.url);
}
```

Then run the program and gave the following URL to the browser.
http://localhost:1337/static/index.html

After when I see the terminal I have seen that the following code line `console.log(req.url);` gave 3 output for me as follows.

```
/static/index.html
/static/tachyons.min.css
/static/ember.jpg
```

In that directory, there are 5 files.

```
chat.css
chat.html
chat.js
ember.jpg
index.html
tachyons.min.css
```

ember.jpg and tachyons.min.css are using for index.html.

**Question is:**

> Although I gave *index.html* as static file Why other 2 file( *which
> is /static/tachyons.min.css & /static/ember.jpg* prints as req.url in
> console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code doesn't serve *only* `index.html` as a static file, it serves any file in that directory which gets requested.  And as you imply here:

> ember.jpg and tachyons.min.css are using for index.html

So if `index.html` references those other two files, then when you request `index.html` in your browser you will also request those other two files.  As the code serves those requests, it logs to the console here:

```
console.log(req.url);
```